# Secure data encryption and validation

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption

Imagine a game for one player, which consists of a number of tests. On completing all of the tests, the player has the option to upload the results to a server - the player who gets the best results wins a big prize. The server needs to be able to validate the result data to see if it has been hacked or even spammed. Any thoughts on how that might be robustly implemented?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can't. Not even with encryption, code obfuscation or anything else. "Never trust the client"!

The only way to make sure no manipulation is involved is having every bit of game logic on the server and exposing only a GUI to the user. You could then send the commands (keystrokes, button clicks, etc.) the player issues to the server, validate them there (even this is not that easy!), handle all the necessary game logic and send back the result.

Of course this is unfeasible if your game involves anything timing-related, because for every player action there will be a delay until the player gets back the result and sees an effect.

For most games all of this is overkill and you just make sure they are difficult to manipulate.

Comment: To elaborate on why it won't work unless the game runs server-side: if you give the application the ability to send trusted data back to the server, and then you give the application to the player, you're giving the player the ability to send trusted data back to the server. So, you're fighting distrustful players by empowering them to send you trusted data, which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-hacking tools are available that can endlessly complicate the communication between server and client, obfuscate memory and routines, modify themselves every time they run, and so on.

Trouble is, most of the anti-hacking tools routinely get hacked, and if the prize is big enough, yours probably will be too. Even rootkits can get rooted. Not to mention the behavior looks so much like a virus that it'll set off warning bells galore and likely end up with a lot of frustrated former customers.

If it's a walled garden like an iPhone, I believe there are tools to ensure the phone isn't jailbroken, I'm not sure if they can be fooled, but that still leaves the problem that anyone could decode the communication and upload their own from something else entirely.

Comment: Ok but if we are to be pragmatic and set our goal as being to simply deter the modestly determined hacker (realising that anyone with sufficient tools and expertise will inevitably be able to bypass any security), then how might one proceed?

Comment: One constraint is that the saved results can't be entirely encrypted - the game needs to be able to load them back in. I can probably append a data block of arbitrary length and format. Some kind of key that identifies the data in the results as validly  generated by a particular user on a particular date with the parameters as described in the results.